# GPU not recognized anymore

Tags: motherboard, gpu, fan

**BIG EDIT 2:**

Ok so after more fiddling around I replaced the RTX 2080 with a GTX 760.

Sometimes the MB beeps sometimes it doesn't, but now, when it doesn't I actually get a video feed and an error message that says

> The VGA card is not supported by UEFI driver. CSM (Compatibility
>   Support Module) settings have been changed for better compatibility.
>   ...

The weirdet part about this is that the PC literally worked perfectly fine with TWO 2080's just the other day.

And I'm so confused by this and why all of a sudden the UEFI driver would not support the cards now.

Absolutely mind boggling!

**BIG EDIT:**

Ok, so I have narrowed down the issue.

All GPU's work on PC B and C, and all PSU's work.

It seems like it's PC A that doesn't recognize any GPU anymore, although it boots up when no GPU is connected.

So we can completely exclude B and C.

PC A sometimes does the 1long-3short beep, which to my MB means VGA error.

I have tried CMOS reset and BIOS update.

Only time it boots is when the GPU is disconnected completely.

Some times when the GPU is connected the MB bypasses it and the GPU fans spin to full speed.

Other than that, it's not being detected.

**OLD QUESTION:**

So, my two RTX 2080 suddenly went blank on my main rig.

Luckily I have 3 computers so I could test them, let's call them A, B and C.

I moved the GPU's in different configs both from A to B and C.
Also single and dual GPU and different PCIe slots.

Sometimes the GPU fans spin to max speed and sometimes they don't, and when they don't, only one fan spins.

I have tried a GTX 1080 in both A and B and it is recognized.

When I tried both of the RTX 2080's in C, they are recognized.

I'm so confused by this.

Sometimes I get 1 long beep and 3 short beeps.

**TL;DR:**

None of the RTX 2080's work on PC A or B, but they do work on C.

The GTX 1080 works on all three PC's.

Both RTX 2080's worked perfectly in single- and dual-gpu config on both A and B yesterday.

Comment: Is there any difference between the power supplies on the systems?

Comment: Yeah. A has the strongest one, B second strongest, C the weakest.

Comment: Any chance the Video Driver did an automatic update causing an issue with power level required by the GPU?

Comment: @John I can not answer that unfortunately. However, I can say that I can't install the drivers as I am getting an error from the nVidia installer that the Windows version is not supported, and/or that no graphics hardware was found.

Remember that the GTX 1080 is recognized though, but not the RTX 2080.

Puzzling.

Comment: @BoogaRoo The beeps signal a VGA error according to the MB manual. Which isn't surprising at this point.

Comment: @vaid Have you tried pc A with the PSU from pc C? Although it may be rated the weakest, it would be good to completely exclude a power issue causing pc A problems. Will the pc A boot with the card in (but not working) - using another graphics port?

Comment: @Mark Yes sir. I have updated the question as I made a little bit of progress.

Comment: Firmware updates on the motherboard for PC A?

Comment: @Sorean Done that.

Comment: So PC A has developed a new fault, most likely with the mother board. If the mobos in guarantee, send it back. If not, replace the mobo.

Comment: @Mark I wouldn't say new, more like newly discovered since I've been trying a bunch of new things out, but yeah, I need to change mobo either way. But it still doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @vaid before you order any new kit, remove all non essential drives and pci cards from the mother board. Try with just 1 memory module ( alternate both). Just in case there's an irq conflict or faulty memory causing the problem

Comment: @Mark Unfortunately same result :/ I'll just have to get a new one.

Comment: @vaid at least you can be fairly sure it's the motherboard now

Comment: @Mark yeah it's for sure the motherboard. Or something with the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Something went bust with the motherboard. Replaced it.